# How to find local minima using Scipy

Tags: python, scipy

I want to find local minimas from an array or list. By the following code I can find local maximas.I know that there exists related questions, but still  I just want to know, if there exists any logic by which I can use the same code for finding local minimas.

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.misc import electrocardiogram
from scipy.signal import find_peaks

x = electrocardiogram()[2000:4000]
peaks, _ = find_peaks(x, height=0)
plt.plot(x)
plt.plot(peaks, x[peaks], "x")
plt.plot(np.zeros_like(x), "--", color="gray")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Not a `scikit-learn` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: Local minima of x are just the local maxima of -x

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about finding the maxima of the negative signal?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.misc import electrocardiogram
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
import numpy as np

x = np.array(electrocardiogram()[2000:4000])
peaks, _ = find_peaks(-x, height=0)
plt.plot(x)
plt.plot(peaks, x[peaks], "x")
plt.plot(np.zeros_like(x), "--", color="gray")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Why would you negate the found Indices that find_peak returns?

Comment: Did you actually run the code? Apart from what @couka correctly points out, the minus sign in `-find_peaks` will give an error (removed).

Comment: The current version works. the error was caused by the fact that electrocardiogram is a list

Comment: for,     x = np.array([4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6 ]) , above code is not working - @desertnaut

Comment: The (now removed by myself) minus sign was causing an error irrelevant of x being a list or a numpy array, and with good cause (`peaks` are array *indices*, and they cannot be negative).

Comment: @WakilKhan for finding the minima of [4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6 ], you should change `find_peaks(-x, height=0)` by `find_peaks(-x)`. If you make this change, the code works.

Comment: @carlorop yes it worked, i changed the code as you said to change, thank you, it helped me a lot

Comment: As @WakilKhan mentioned, we must remove the `height=0`. The explanation is that `height=0` means  "Let’s find all peaks (local maxima) in x whose amplitude lies above 0.", however as `-x` returns negative values, it just finds 0. See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html